# MySQL: wee bit different kind of master detail sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've the following scenario:

```
Table 1
group_id
location

Table 2
group_id
empname
```

I need the following output:

```
group_id, location, empname
1         ABC        NULL
1         ABC        XYZ
1         ABC        PQR
```

so the first row is the master row and the rest of the rows are all detail rows for that master.

How can i get this output?

TIA

Bo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.group_id,t1.location,NULL AS empname FROM Table1 t1
UNION
SELECT t1.group_id,t1.location,t2.empname 
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.group_id=t2.group_id
ORDER BY 1,3
```

**EDIT:**
Just alias the 3rd column of the first SQL Statement as `empname`.

Comment: +1 Just alias the null: `CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(100)) as empname`. Then you can do: `ORDER BY group_id, empname`

Comment: @MichaelBuen. You are right to using alias of that null. But I would not like to CAST NULL AS VARCHAR. Because the output should display NULL at Master row.

Comment: It will still display null even you cast it as varchar. Or you can reverse the union, ORDER BY applies on all the queries of UNION, not on the last one only

Comment: hmm.. is that(`NULL as empname`) allowed in MySQL? In SQL Server, it enforces that the aligned column must have the same type(and even the size), hence the need for cast. Anyway, it's good to know that it's allowed not to cast in MySQL ツ On your edit, just change the `ORDER BY 1,3` to `ORDER BY group_id, empname`